# Select multi file with FileDialog don't work

Tags: java, awt, processing, macos-mojave, filedialog

When the window dialog is open I cannot select more than one file.

```
void setup() {
  size(100,100);
  select_multi_files_via_FileDialog();
}

import java.awt.FileDialog;
import java.awt.Frame;
File [] select_multi_files;
void select_multi_files_via_FileDialog() {
  Frame frame = null;
  FileDialog dialog = new FileDialog(frame, "select file", FileDialog.LOAD);
  dialog.setVisible(true);
  dialog.setMultipleMode(true);
  String directory = dialog.getDirectory();
  println("multifile is",dialog.isMultipleMode());
  select_multi_files = dialog.getFiles();

  if(select_multi_files != null && select_multi_files.length > 0) {
    printArray(select_multi_files);
  }
}
```

I want to be able to select one or more files in the dialog window but I am not able to multi-select with `SHIFT` or `CTRL`

The console outputs:

```
2019-03-31 07:29:28.173 java[1808:250416] warning: <NSRemoteView: 0x7fc2801911b0> determined it was necessary to configure <NSOpenPanel: 0x7fc2798f75e0> to support remote view vibrancy
multifile is true
[0] /Users/stan/En_cours/BOULOT/MEDIA/MEDIA ROMANESCO/FILM/extrait_film/alien_1_9e_pasager_ripley_extrait.mov
```

I don't know if it's a bug from OSX-Mojave, from Java, from `NSRemoteView`, from `NSOpenPanel` or if I am missing something in my code?

Answer (score 2):

To enable multi-select you just need to change the order of calls to the file dialog

From:

```
FileDialog dialog = new FileDialog(frame, "select file", FileDialog.LOAD);
dialog.setVisible(true);
dialog.setMultipleMode(true);
```

To:

```
FileDialog dialog = new FileDialog(frame, "select file", FileDialog.LOAD);
dialog.setMultipleMode(true);
dialog.setVisible(true);
```